# Collecting row stats from distributed matrix in Spark (Java)

Tags: java, matrix, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I am trying to multiply two large matrices and find indexes of biggest 20 or so elements for each row of resulting fairly large (50000x50000) matrix. I hope to use Spark with java for this. I found I can multiply distributed matrices if I store them as BlockMatrices. But otherwise there do not seem to be any more complex operations available for distributed matrices and I am stuck. What would be the best way to do such operation? Simple code I have so far looks something like this:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
BlockMatrix A = getBlockMatrixA(sc);
BlockMatrix B = getBlockMatrixB(sc);
BlockMatrix AB = A.multiply(B);
```

Comment: I think you might want to make use of Spark mllib's matrix format instead of contructing blocks, since everything is optimized. https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix

Comment: I will want to add and multiply A and B a few times and they are quite big. All the other distributed matrix formats seem only to support multiplication with other local matrix, whereas I can multiply two block matrices, so I though this would be faster?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should hopefully do the thing, though I have not tested it yet:

```
RDD<IndexedRow> byRow = AB.toIndexedRowMatrix().rows();
JavaRDD<IndexedRow> dummyRDD = sc.parallelize(new ArrayList<IndexedRow>());
JavaRDD<IndexedRow> javaByRow = dummyRDD.wrapRDD(byRow);
JavaPairRDD<Long, List<Long>> top20byRow = javaByRow.mapToPair(
new PairFunction<IndexedRow, Long, List<Long>>() {
    public Tuple2<Long, List<Long>> call(IndexedRow ir) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2<Long, List<Long>>(ir.index(), getTopN(ir.vector(),N));
    }
});
```